# mssql backup expiration date month and day part changed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, date, database-backups

I have a problem with the expiration date of my database backups

The expiration date is set, but the month and day part are changed. For example the expiration date should be **"04.06.2017"** but at the restore window of the *SQL Server Management Studio* it is **"06.04.2017"**.

I create the backup with a program written in *C#*. I tried anything I could think up, to change the date to the correct way, but nothing worked. With the date like this, the backups overwritten daily and on later dates in the month, it can't do the backups because **"06.13.2017"** is not a valid *Date*.

Has someone an idea what I can do?

My C#-Code for the backup:

```
Backup bkpDBFullWithCompression = new Backup();
bkpDBFullWithCompression.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
bkpDBFullWithCompression.Database = db;
//bkpDBFullWithCompression.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
bkpDBFullWithCompression.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\backup_likesoft\" + "bkpDBFullWithCompression.Database + ".bak", DeviceType.File);
bkpDBFullWithCompression.BackupSetName = bkpDBFullWithCompression.Database + " database Backup - Compressed";
bkpDBFullWithCompression.BackupSetDescription = bkpDBFullWithCompression.Database + " database - Full Backup with Compressin -only in SQL Server 2008";
bkpDBFullWithCompression.SqlBackup(mServer);
```

Thanks

Comment: No, they aren't changed. June 4 is 6/4 in the US and 4/6 elsewhere. Dates aren't presented with dots anyway. Where did you find this string? It looks like a *localized* string generated by an application. German UI maybe?

Comment: Yes this are localized strings from the application. I think sql server is working with the US Dates in the background, that the expiration dates gets changed. Is there any possibility to change this? The start- and end-date for the backup process are correct shown.

Comment: No, SQL Server isn't working with any *string format*. Dates are binary values. What you see are localization display differences for the very same date value. If anything, fix the application. Use either the invariant culture, or allow the user to change the culture or whatever.

Comment: If you want to check for problems, use SQL commands in SSMS and use ISO8601 or the unseparated date format to specify dates. You'll see that there aren't any changes.

Comment: I don't think the SSMS is the problem. I think something gets messed up, when the programm saves the backup. I already tryed the different DateTimeKind's which C# and .net have and it was every time the same result, but as i tryed, just in case, and set a new datetime with changed month and day, there was the correct date. But this solution is also only working till the 12th of a month so, i'm trying something else.

Comment: You misunderstand. You are looking at the same date, formated in the US order in one case, in the European order in the other. I'd suspect German, due to the dots. `DateTimeKind` is about timezones. Theres nothing to "fix" with the dates. You have to fix the way the application displays and parses dates.

Comment: BTW where is the code? You haven't explained where that string comes from. Is it part of the file name? Something that appears in the debug info automatically? How do you retrieve this value? Where is the code that fails to parse this, and why does it read a string at all? If you used SMO, this should be available as a DateTime.

Comment: I postet the code of my backup programm. The date i postet isn't a string. I only Highlightet it this way, so it is better visible and nothing more. The value it self i did see in the SSMS recovery side for Databases.

Comment: And? Where did you try to parse this? *Why* did you try to parse it? Your own code shows that you use a `DateTime` to set the expiry date, not a string. Please post a *complete*, *reproducible* example that shows the problem. Right now I suspect you still confuse the different formats used to display the very same date

Comment: To put it another way - don't you think DBAs would have noticed such a problem 20 years ago? You are even targeting a 10 year old version. You can't even say that this is something that appeared in a new version

Comment: I never said, that i tryed anything to parse. I set the ExpiriationDate as DateTime and save the Backup and than look in the SSMS recovery, if the Expirationdate was set and correctly and nothing else. I never tryed to read any DateTime from the backup file. The above is all code i wrote. Anything else i did, was using Microsoft products, to look up, if seting the expiration date worked an nothing else, and there i saw the turned Date and nothing else.

Comment: `With the date like this, the backups overwritten daily and on later dates in the month, it can't do the backups because "06.13.2017" is not a valid Date.` What does this mean then? What does `can't do the backups` mean and why are you saying this isn't a valid date? Do you have an actual problem, or do you assume you may have one?

Comment: I'll repeat this. There are thousands of installations in Europe. If there was any problem people would have noticed. Explain what you did and what the problem is so others can reproduce it. Right now, it's not reproducible

Comment: The date 06.13.2017 means the 6 day of the 13 month in german. I tested it with the actual day and made a backup which should expie on the 4. June, but with the changed day in month for german way of using the Date, it got the 6 April and overwrote anytime the backup, instead to make a new entry, because the set wasn't expired. I don't think this is reproduceable for you, but i hope you understood the problem with the turned month and day. This is also already obsolete, like i said in an earlyer post, because i used some other way.

Comment: I suspect there are several thousand installations in Germany too. And we also use dd/MM. Post the steps to reproduce this behaviour. Even if you call Microsoft Support, they'll ask for steps to reproduce this. I doubt they'll be able to do so. The steps should be `Run this specific backup command, then this command, then this command. I expected two files, I got 1 file.`. You can click on the script button at the top left of the backup box to generate the backup command that corresponds to the options you selected

Comment: I wrote my backup code=> run the programm => opened SSMS => selected database => selected backup on the database => selected the point restore from medium => selected the path to my backup => looked at the set of data and the expiration date => closed the window => rerun the program => and did the steps again to look up the set and saw that there wasn't two sets like expectet, but just one with another time stamp but the same day and this shouldn't happen, if the DateTime is the same regardless how it is shown. So if there isn't any confusion with the date, how can this happen?